# Find out call amount of Class, when autowired

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, dependency-injection

So following Setup: I have Eclipse and a Spring-based Project. I currently want to analyse classes, concerning how much influence they have. To do that, I want to see how often Class A for example gets called, or is set as a private field (I mostly use @Autowired to inject objects).

When I mark Class A for example anywhere in the project, right click and select 'Call Hierarchy' it only shows me where in my project I use 'new Class A()', but I almost never do that.

So what would be a way to measure, how many instances of a class I have in my project? Maybe a plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure you can do this using some of the methods involving threads, but I think they might be a bad way of doing it - correct me if I'm wrong. You could always create a global count variable and incremement this every time Class A is called.

Comment: @JamesLloyd I think he wants to do static analysis, i.e. on the source only

Comment: You may want "Find Usage", not "Call Hierarchy".

Comment: If you don't inject using interfaces you could check where the class name is used (`ctrl` + `shift + `g` or `References`->`Workspace`/`Project`) which also reports imports etc. but should provide more results (or just look for imports of the class).